# Drush does not work in local environment when setting up a site with Lando

Tags: drush

I am trying to set up a Drupal site on my local using Lando and I am facing issues while using drush, on `drush cr` I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Drush\Log\Logger::__construct(), 0 passed in /app/vendor/drush/drush/includes/drush.inc on line 1281 and exactly 1 expected in /app/vendor/drush/drush/src/Log/Logger.php:29

Stack trace:

#0 /app/vendor/drush/drush/includes/drush.inc(1281): Drush\Log\Logger->__construct()

#1 /app/vendor/drush/drush/includes/preflight.inc(152): _drush_create_default_logger()

#2 /app/vendor/drush/drush/includes/preflight.inc(28): drush_preflight_prepare()

#3 /app/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(12): drush_main()

#4 {main}

  thrown in /app/vendor/drush/drush/src/Log/Logger.php on line 29
```

drupal version: 9

drush version: 10

Comment: Drupal 9 and Drush 10 are both long out of date, it would be advisable to upgrade to recent versions and try again.

Comment: As you mentioned Lando, I assume you already decided to build up your site in this specific environment. Lando offers a quite stable and well-documented pre-composed solution for installing Drupal-based websites. Their recipe comes already bundled with the latest compatible version of Drush, Composer, MySQL, and other necessary/useful accessories – https://docs.lando.dev/plugins/drupal/